# Is it ok to feed a light from a partially-switched outlet?

Tags: electrical

I have a switched plug (Half hot duplex receptacle).
top plug is hot all the time and bottom plug is switched and is hot when switch is on.
is against the code is I wire a light from switched part of the duplex? 
So I can use the switch to turn on and of the light.,

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, assuming you did it correctly.

Comment: Do you want the receptacle to stay half-switched? Also, is power brought in at the receptacle, or at the switch?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But just as easily, you could change it so the switch **only** switches a hardwired light and the receptacles are not switched at all. When I moved into my house, I had someone do that and install a ceiling fixture (now I would do it myself - 120V electrical scared me back then, plus no easy looking things up on the internet at that time) in all the bedrooms.